# too few arguments to function in 'function(int ans)'

Tags: c

this is my function declaration

```
int boygroups(int ans);
```

and this is my function definition

```
int boygroups(int ans) {             
switch (p) {
    case 1: printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t1. %s\n",songs[0].una);
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. %s\n",songs[0].pangalawa);
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. %s\n",songs[0].pangatlo);
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. %s\n",songs[0].pangapat); 
        break; 
    case 2: printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t1. %s\n",songs[1].una);
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. %s\n",songs[1].pangalawa);
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. %s\n",songs[1].pangatlo);
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. %s\n",songs[1].pangapat); 
        break;
    case 3: printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t1. %s\n",songs[2].una);
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. %s\n",songs[2].pangalawa);
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. %s\n",songs[2].pangatlo);
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. %s\n",songs[2].pangapat);      
        break;
    case 4: printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t1. %s\n",songs[3].una);
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. %s\n",songs[3].pangalawa);
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. %s\n",songs[3].pangatlo);
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. %s\n",songs[3].pangapat);       
        break; 

}        
}
```

My declaration and definition is the same, i don't know why i keep getting an error like this.

Comment: I don't see any errors here.  What does the error look like exactly?  On what line number does it occur?

Comment: How are you calling `boygroups`? Also, what is `p`?

Comment: Where is the function named `function()`?

Comment: i just changed the function boygroup to function to make it general.

Comment: @deibaby03 The please update the code in your question, or change the name in the title. Additionally, please also include the statement that calls your `function()` or  `boygroups()` in your question.

Comment: The point to look at is how you called your function..

Comment: Didn't your compiler tell you the line number of the error? Why don't you show us that line?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplifiying the whole thing to:

```
int boygroups(int ans) {
  printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t1. %s\n",songs[p-1].una);
        printf("\t\t\t\t2. %s\n",songs[p-1].pangalawa);
        printf("\t\t\t\t3. %s\n",songs[p-1].pangatlo);
        printf("\t\t\t\t4. %s\n",songs[p-1].pangapat);       
}
```

This is equivalent to your boygroups function, but much shorter.

Comment: ... apart from the lack of bounds checking ;-)

Comment: @Roddy: sure, but anyway we don't know where `p` comes from, maybe it is already known to be inside correct bounds.